# How to register a callback to execute on a file change in linux?

Tags: c, linux, polling

I'm writing a little linux utility in C that will monitor a virtual device that exposes basic data (e.g. temperature sensor).  I want to avoid polling the file (e.g. by continuously `cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`) and instead register a callback to execute on changes to that file.  Requirements are not realtime at all.

How can I avoid continuously reading that file as fast as I can?

Comment: you can use inotify ...

Comment: Refer http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/inotify/demo_inotify.c.html

Comment: I believe `inotify` might not work for pseudo filesystems like `/proc/` or `/sys/`

Answer (score 6):

For many *local* filesystems, you could use (Linux specific) [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities (to monitor changes in the filesystem or in plain files or directories).

However, `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) and `/sys/` (STFW on [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)) are *special* filesystems with pseudo-files in them. AFAIK (but I could be wrong, so please check) `inotify` won't work on them.

In your particular case of probing the temperatures, I would say that the simplest thing to do is indeed to repeatedly [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), and [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) that  `/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` pseudo file. You could do that in some loop which e.g. [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) a few seconds, or maybe [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) or [usleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) some tenths of seconds, or take advantage of your existing [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) or perhaps put the loop in some other thread. See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

<sup>(For physical reasons, temperature does not vary rapidly, no need to probe it every millisecond; and reading it too often would require some CPU and warm a bit the computer and the thermal probe!)</sup>

I tend to believe that multiplexing & polling syscalls à la [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the nearly obsolete `select`) don't work well with pseudo-files from `/sys/`, but I could be wrong.

If you are using some GUI toolkit framework, it surely already gives you some ways to set up periodic callbacks (e.g. [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) for GTK, or [timers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html) in Qt). Use them wisely. No need to probe the temperature more than twice or four times per second.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inotify library to monitor individual files or directories.

Example:

```
 #include <sys/inotify.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include "tlpi_hdr.h"

 static void             /* Display information from inotify_event structure */
 displayInotifyEvent(struct inotify_event *i)
 {
     printf("    wd =%2d; ", i->wd);
     if (i->cookie > 0)
         printf("cookie =%4d; ", i->cookie);

     printf("mask = ");
     if (i->mask & IN_ACCESS)        printf("IN_ACCESS ");
     if (i->mask & IN_ATTRIB)        printf("IN_ATTRIB ");
     if (i->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE) printf("IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)   printf("IN_CLOSE_WRITE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_CREATE)        printf("IN_CREATE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_DELETE)        printf("IN_DELETE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)   printf("IN_DELETE_SELF ");
     if (i->mask & IN_IGNORED)       printf("IN_IGNORED ");
     if (i->mask & IN_ISDIR)         printf("IN_ISDIR ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MODIFY)        printf("IN_MODIFY ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MOVE_SELF)     printf("IN_MOVE_SELF ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)    printf("IN_MOVED_FROM ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)      printf("IN_MOVED_TO ");
     if (i->mask & IN_OPEN)          printf("IN_OPEN ");
     if (i->mask & IN_Q_OVERFLOW)    printf("IN_Q_OVERFLOW ");
     if (i->mask & IN_UNMOUNT)       printf("IN_UNMOUNT ");
     printf("\n");

     if (i->len > 0)
         printf("        name = %s\n", i->name);
 }

 #define BUF_LEN (10 * (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1))

 int
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     int inotifyFd, wd, j;
     char buf[BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(8)));
     ssize_t numRead;
     char *p;
     struct inotify_event *event;

     if (argc < 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
         usageErr("%s pathname...\n", argv[0]);

     inotifyFd = inotify_init();                 /* Create inotify instance */
     if (inotifyFd == -1)
         errExit("inotify_init");

     /* For each command-line argument, add a watch for all events */

     for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
         wd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, argv[j], IN_ALL_EVENTS);
         if (wd == -1)
             errExit("inotify_add_watch");

         printf("Watching %s using wd %d\n", argv[j], wd);
     }

     for (;;) {                                  /* Read events forever */
         numRead = read(inotifyFd, buf, BUF_LEN);
         if (numRead == 0)
             fatal("read() from inotify fd returned 0!");

         if (numRead == -1)
             errExit("read");

         printf("Read %ld bytes from inotify fd\n", (long) numRead);

         /* Process all of the events in buffer returned by read() */

         for (p = buf; p < buf + numRead; ) {
             event = (struct inotify_event *) p;
             displayInotifyEvent(event);

             p += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
         }
     }

     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

You can see full detail in that link: 
http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/inotify/demo_inotify.c.html
or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Are you sure that inotify facilities work on pseudo files from `/sys/` ? I believe they don't but I could be wrong.